How to add custom checkout fields in checkout based on blocks?
The new woocommerce checkout looks beautiful, but I can't add 2 custom fields by traditional way
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_fields');
function custom_checkout_fields($checkout) {
    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field">';
    
    woocommerce_form_field('delivery_date', array(
        'type'        => 'date',
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'       => __('Delivery Date'),
        'placeholder' => __('Select a delivery date'),
        'required'    => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value('delivery_date'));
    
    woocommerce_form_field('occasion', array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'       => __('Occasion'),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter the occasion'),
    ), $checkout->get_value('occasion'));
    
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_field_process');
function custom_checkout_field_process() {
    if (!$_POST['delivery_date']) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Please select a delivery date.'), 'error');
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id) {
    if (!empty($_POST['delivery_date'])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'delivery_date', sanitize_text_field($_POST['delivery_date']));
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['occasion'])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'occasion', sanitize_text_field($_POST['occasion']));
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1);
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    $delivery_date = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'delivery_date', true);
    $occasion = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'occasion', true);
    
    if (!empty($delivery_date)) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . __('Delivery Date') . ':</strong> ' . $delivery_date . '</p>';
    }
    if (!empty($occasion)) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . __('Occasion') . ':</strong> ' . $occasion . '</p>';
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_checkout_field_email_order_meta_keys');
function custom_checkout_field_email_order_meta_keys($fields) {
    $fields['delivery_date'] = __('Delivery Date');
    $fields['occasion'] = __('Occasion');
    return $fields;
}

Is there a specific way for new block based checkout to add new fields or I will have to switch to old [woocommerce_checkout] shortcode and do all scripts and styles manually?
Good new cart, but it has to be flexible.

For checkout block, checkout date fields are not handled, only "checkbox", "text"  and "select" field types are allowed. See WooCommerce Block - Additional Checkout Fields official documentation. So you should better switch to WooCommerce Legacy Checkout (shortcode).
